# How do I give an HTML canvas the keyboard focus using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I am implementing a game using Javascript, jquery, and the Canvas tag. How can I prevent the browser from processing keyboard shortcuts when the canvas tag has the focus? I have tried event.stopPropagation() and it has no effect.

I can pick up keyboard events. However, when the user presses the spacebar, the web page scrolls down in Firefox. The same happens with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The root problem is that by default the browser doesn't make the canvas "focusable".  The best workaround I could come up with is to set the `tabindex` on the canvas:

```
$("#canvas")
    // Add tab index to ensure the canvas retains focus
    .attr("tabindex", "0")
    // Mouse down override to prevent default browser controls from appearing
    .mousedown(function(){ $(this).focus(); return false; }) 
    .keydown(function(){ /* ... game logic ... */ return false; });
```

If for whatever reason you can't set the `tabindex`, you can also make the canvas "focusable" by setting `contentEditable` to true:

```
// Add content editable to help ensure the canvas retains focus
$("#canvas").attr("contentEditable", "true")
$("#canvas")[0].contentEditable = true;
```

This is the solution I came up with originally, but in my opinion it's a bit hackier than the `tabindex` option.

Another thing to consider is that browsers tend to outline content editable elements with a border.  This can be off-putting to some users. Luckily, you can get rid of it with this bit of css:

```
#canvas { outline: none; }
```

I've tested both solutions in Chrome 3/4/5 and FireFox 3.0/3.5/3.6 on Windows XP, Mac OSX and Linux.  Here's a working example: http://xavi.co/static/so-canvas-keyboard.html

Comment: This works in FF and Chrome, and even in latest ie but i wanted to note that in IE it will cause you to scroll to top of the element on every click because of the way IE treats tabindex and contentEditable

Answer (score 3):

Try `event.preventDefault();`. Also there are `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events... you could try each of them to see which works.

Comment: Woot. This seems to be the proper solution. Works for me. Although be careful how you use this, as you might inadvertently disable other useful keyboard browser shortcuts in the process.