# event on pressing enter javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener

whenever i press on either up or down button i can check if those key were pressed for example an alert will be fired here :

```
 if ((38 in keysDown) ) { // Player holding up

       window.alert("up button was pressed");
 }


 if ((40 in keysDown) ) { // Player holding down

       window.alert("down button was pressed");
 }
```

but here even tho i press on enter the alert doesnt play

```
if ((13 in keysDown) ) { // player pushed on enter
       window.alert("enter key was pressed"); // here nothing happen
}
```

i am using those 3 lines right at the start to add a event listner:

```
   keysDown = {};
   addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;}, false);
   addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {delete keysDown[e.keyCode];}, false);
```

but for some reason which i dont know of the enter key doesnt work
the problem occurs on firefox , working fine on Chrome and on IE

thanks in advance.

**EDIT** i figure out the problem, the canvas which i am using doesnt have focus,
so the enter button doesnt work, can any1 tell me how to switch focus ?

Comment: does this happen in every browser? which browser did you noticed it? can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: i used firefox ... i need it to work mainly on firefox

Comment: checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SUkG/) works for me in firefox... shows keyCode 13

Comment: let me guess: you're trying to capture the enter key in a `<textarea>` ?

Comment: works good for me in fiddle aswell but not when i use my code

Comment: try to check another of the key properties... if you use jQuery you can be sure they normalize everything in the event.which property... else you could anyway check event.which (this is supported in firefox natively I think)

Comment: i think that the problem is with the focus , any idea how to switch the focus from the button that is being pressed to the canvas ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your code? that might actually be easier to understand / reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT i figure out the problem, the canvas which i am using doesnt have
>   focus, so the enter button doesnt work, can any1 tell me how to switch
>   focus ?

sure.
[How do you set focus to the HTML5 canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771/how-do-you-set-focus-to-the-html5-canvas-element)

or even better:

**1- Tabindex:**

```
$("#canvas")
    // Add tab index to ensure the canvas retains focus
    .attr("tabindex", "0")
    // Mouse down override to prevent default browser controls from appearing
    .mousedown(function(){ $(this).focus(); return false; }) 
    .keydown(function(){ /* ... bla bla bla ... */ return false; });
```

**2- setting contentEditable to true:**

```
// Add content editable to help ensure the canvas retains focus
$("#canvas").attr("contentEditable", "true")
$("#canvas")[0].contentEditable = true;
```

source: [How do I give an HTML canvas the keyboard focus using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829586/how-do-i-give-an-html-canvas-the-keyboard-focus-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The key code for enter is 13.

Here is a simple event method on detecting the press of the enter key:

EDIT:I edited my post with something much more simple:

```
    function check() {
        if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.write("Enter pressed");
        }
    }

<body onkeypress="check()">
</body>
```

Comment: I think this will only work in Chrome... here the current event object is stored in window.event... but this is not working in other browsers imho

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.which` in Firefox and `event.keyCode` in IE.