# Checking Keyboard or Mouse events are done in a Div

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a keyboard or mouse event is done inside of a div?

Once I check the onmousemove() event of a div it works but onkeyup, onkeypress etc are not working for the div.

What is the reason for that?

```
<div onmousemove="alert(1);" onkeypress="alert(2);">
```

Here alert(1) will be displayed but alert(2) is not displayed.

Comment: what do you mean with keyboard event "inside" a div? Do you mean a keyboard event while the mouse is hovering above the div?

Comment: no.when i enter a key on div want to display alert also like moving mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div must have focus.
Here is how you do it:

### 1- Tabindex:

```
// JQ
$("#divID")
    .attr("tabindex", "0")
    .keydown(function(){ /* ... bla bla bla ... */ return false; });
```

Or

```
// JS
<div id="divID"
     width="500px"
     height="500px"
     tabindex="1">
</div>
```

### 2- setting contentEditable to true:

```
$("#divID").attr("contentEditable", "true")
```

Or

```
$("#divID")[0].contentEditable = true;
```

### Links:

[How do I give an HTML canvas the keyboard focus using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829586/how-do-i-give-an-html-canvas-the-keyboard-focus-using-jquery)
[How do you set focus to the HTML5 canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771/how-do-you-set-focus-to-the-html5-canvas-element)

Comment: I think in the second second example of "2-" you have to use `$("#divID")[0].contentEditable = true;` because it is a property of the node and not of the collection...

Answer (score 2):

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDYH2/). you cannot fire key events on an element that does not allow you to focus and input... it might be possible with `contenteditable` but I am not sure... when you do a keypress inside of the input of the fiddle the onkeypress of the div is triggering

EDIT: I just discovered that you can also set up a tabindex="0" on the div and therefore make it focussable (see the updated [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDYH2/1/)) then no input is needed BUT it interferes when using TAB key to walt through focussable elements